# Зайдика, заберика, подайка... Вопрос о добавочном "ка".

Tags: окончание

В быту люди часто добавляют к глаголам окончание «ка», что делает их речь достаточно фамильярной, а, подчас,  и грубой. Читая книги на старорусском языке, я понял, откуда в современные глаголы пришло окончание «ся». Ранее говорили: «умыть ся», то есть - умыть себя, «побрить ся» - побрить себя и т.д. Понятно, что семантика глаголов с окончанием «ся» сейчас более расширена. Например: бороться,  не значит – бороть себя, скорее - бороться самому, но разговор не об этом. Меня интересует происхождение именно этого «ка». Единственное, что могу предположить, это то, что  в словах с подобным окончанием слышится при-**ка**-з. Пример: «Уходика ты, пока цел!» То есть, не просто уходи, а уходи при «**ка**», уходи – это приказ. Понимаю, что это всего лишь мои домыслы, возможно, весьма далёкие от истины. "Помогитека разобраться!" - Это шутка. Помогите, пожалуйста, разобраться!

Comment: >Читая книги на старорусском языке, я понял, откуда в современные глаголы пришло окончание «ся». Ранее говорили: «умыть ся», то есть - умыть себя, «побрить ся» - побрить себя и т.д.

Кое-где у славян это **"ся"** могло ставиться даже ПЕРЕД глаголом. Такое сохранилось, к примеру, в некоторых районах Западной Украины. Слушать подобное нелегко, но забавно. :-)

Например, рождественское выражение: *"Христос ся родить. Славимо його"*. (Христос рождается. Славим его.)

Про **-ка** вопрос интересный. От меня +1.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

У сабжа, кроме формы *-ка* существует и форма *-ко* : на-ко, ну-ко, подай-ко, налей-ко и т.п.

> Максим Горький. Гривенник (1916)
> Но она, не взглянув на меня, попросила: ― **Налей-ко** в рукомойник воды… Вымыла свои тонкие пальчики, аккуратно вытерла их один за другим и, взглянув в окно, сказала...
>
> Г.И. Успенский. Овца без стада (1877)
> И свинья понюхает этот лимонад ― и прочь! .. **Налей-ко мне**, Марк!
>
> Владимир Личутин. Вдова Нюра (1973)
> Вот и сына принесла Катька, а этой осенью и другого: **ну-ко, на-ко**, приехала к Нюре рожать да на Нюриной кровати и принесла парничка...

Если **ко** первоначально, а форма **ка** вторична из-за аканья, то можно сравнить побудительную частицу -ко с древним предлогом **къ** :
*приходи ко мне в гости!*
*приходи-ко в гости!*
Таким образом, возможно понимание нашей частицы в качестве *побуждения-приглашения* (***ко мне, к нам***) :

> Василий Белов. Плотницкие рассказы (1968)
> ― Надо бы, батюшко, радиво наладить, у меня в избе радиво заглохло. **Приди-ко вечером-то**, приди.

В справочных материалах утверждается, что частица -ка непроизводная, не восходит к каким-то другим частям речи. Но я думаю, что с древнерусским предлогом **къ** все же связь имеется.

(Все примеры - Нацкорпус)

Comment: На мой взгляд, вы абсолютно правы! Теперь я уверен, что это так. Спасибо за ответ.

Answer (score 1):

Черных однозначно указывает на связь частицы КО и предлога К/КО, и это неудивительно: предлог указывает направление, и частица выражает просьбу, совет, принуждение, как бы усиливает направленность.

Интересно, что на Севере и в Сибири частица КА используется и в других случаях (как приговорка), например: "у меня-ка сродник есть, мне-ка чо, тамо-ка (=там)".